# Cannot Resolve Host Or Access Website Through Router

Tags: wireless-networking, ping, hostname, traceroute

This is weird. I am on Windows XP with **Edimax BR 6204Wg**. I have 3 devices - 2 laptops and 1 smartphone. 1st laptop and smartphone are connected through WiFi to router and 2nd laptop is connected through LAN to router. Before firmware upgrade i did not try to access website but after firmware upgrade to latest version:

http://www.edimax.eu/en/support_detail.php?pd_id=11&pl1_id=3#02

i had problems resolving host, pinging, tracerting and accessing website. Sometimes ping and tracert work but i cannot access website and sometimes i can access website but ping and tracert do not work. **Weird?**

I downgraded to previous version and no changes.

If i can no longer access that website through Internet Explorer, i can access it in Firefox. I tried deleting cookies, clearing cache and that seem not make difference. Switching LAN port did not make difference.

When i disconnect router and connect laptop through LAN to internet modem, everything is normal. I tried resetting router, resetting to factory default settings and all did not help.

At the moment i can access website on laptop connected through LAN from Firefox and Internet Explorer, but on my smartphone i can access website only with Opera but not with built-in browser and Skyfire.

**UPDATE:** I just could only access with Internet Explorer but not with other browsers on my PC. Minutes later i could access with all browsers. But on smartphone i could only access with Opera and not with other browsers. I am confused.

I also determined that sometimes i can access and sometimes can't. What is also weird is that when ping and tracert cannot resolve host, i still am able to access website.

Comment: Despite being long, your question is thin on actual information.  What WWW site?  [What are the error messages?](http://homepage.ntlworld.com./jonathan.deboynepollard/FGA/problem-report-standard-litany.html)