# Cannot Access Website First Time Through Router And Later It Seems To Forget Routing Table

Tags: mac, dns, wireless-router, modem, hostname

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Cannot Resolve Host Or Access Website Through Router](https://superuser.com/questions/302693/cannot-resolve-host-or-access-website-through-router)

Would be helpful to those who are willing to help with this one. I evaluated the problem and it is for computer networker and router and modem specialist more like.

I first posted about problem **[here](https://superuser.com/questions/302693/cannot-resolve-host-or-access-website-through-router)**.

Additional problems that i noticed is that when i access website first, it tells me internet address not found and after several moments i can access website. After maybe 30 minutes or 1 hour if i try to access same website again, i get former error.

There is a problem also when webpage loads only partially and has a messed up structure:

[image: this image]

It was rarely previously i was getting this because i connected directly to modem but now it occurs more frequently.

I tried doing what was suggested **[in this post](https://superuser.com/questions/302693/cannot-resolve-host-or-access-website-through-router)** and it did not do anything. I tried with Edimax and 3Com routers and they just can't forget routing table both, right? They must be technically fine i think. Also i updated to latest drivers both, disabled firewall, protected with WPA etc. Also when happened that i could not connect to website, i "repaired windows connection" and then website loaded, but i think it wasn't because i repaired but due to fact that as i mentioned earlier that after first attempt connecting, after several moments website loads.

Guys, i almost ran out of ideas and final idea i thought of is to buy somekind of splitter to divide bandwidth between laptop (LAN) and wireless router (LAN) like HUB/Router/Switch?

What would you recommend?

Comment: Please don't ask a new question if you have new info. Just edit the old one.