# How To Connect Internet Modem To 2 LAN Devices?

Tags: internet, wireless-router, switch, cable-modem, dsl-modem

I have unresolved problem with **[router and modem](https://superuser.com/questions/307734/cannot-access-website-first-time-through-router-and-later-it-seems-to-forget-rout)**, so can i do this with HUB or switch but not with router?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A router has a built in switch. A hub or switch alone will only be useful if you have 2+ public IP addresses. The router has a DHCP server built in which will allow multiple LAN connections to one WAN.

Comment: If you have been switching between router and direct connect, make sure the new device is registered with your ISP. Often the ISP will not have the new device registered and therefore not allow access. This could explain why you have access with some connections but not others

Comment: Do you mean to CLONE MAC address? If yes, then i assume router's MAC address?

Comment: You there? I waited some time for your response.

Comment: It really has nothing to do with Cloning MAC addresses. Basically, you have one IP address from your provider and you need to have multiple devices connect to the internet. In order to do this, you will need to create a private network of your devices. To do this, you will need a DHCP Server. Routers have a built in DHCP server in them. On a router, you'll typically see 5 ports. One port is the WAN. The other four ports are LAN. those four LAN ports are what's called a switch. Switches will expand the number of ports and connections available to a DHCP server.

Comment: Hubs are basically the original/stupid switch. Take a scenario where you have a four computers. You have 1, 2, 3, and 4. If computer 1 is pulling data from computer 2 (for arguments sake lets say 1GB) then this may take some time. Lets say your hub has a 100mb/s connection, this will use up your entire hub's bandwidth for 80 seconds. If computer 3 and computer 4 and also transferring data then their speeds and c1 and c2 speeds will suffer. Hubs are dumb. Switches would see that c1 and c2 and transferring. They'll xfer at 100mb/s. It will see c3 and c4 are xferring and will xfer at 100mb/s.

Comment: Now a days, you cannot find hubs around. They are obsolete for the most part. (i still use some in my basement for some special projects, but that is a different story). You want a router. Go to your local store and purchase a $50 wireless router.